# MessageContext not available in REST-Service

Tags: rest, web-services, jboss, jax-rs, illegalstateexception

I have a REST service in a JBoss environment and am unable to retrieve the `MessageContext`.

The service looks like this:

```
@Path("/mypath")
public class MyService {

  @Resource
  protected WebServiceContext wsContext;

  @POST
  @Path("{partnerId}")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void create(@NotNull @PathParam("partnerId") String partnerId,
        DataTO data) {
    // will cause an IllegalStateException
    wsContext.getMessageContext();
  }
}
```

The registration in the service looks like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Why is the exception thrown? What do I need to change?

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: The exception (including no message) is the following:
```java.lang.IllegalStateException

    at org.jboss.ws.common.injection.ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.getWebServiceContext(ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.java:88)

    at org.jboss.ws.common.injection.ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.getMessageContext(ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.java:69)

    at fr.xxx.fwmc.arch.isolation.wsserver.bean.CommonWSActivityBean.init(CommonWSActivityBean.java:88)```

Comment: In a similar context https://developer.jboss.org/thread/204411 explains that the `MessageContext` might be not initialized yet. However, I am in request here, am I not?